# Is Four a Divergent?

Tags: divergent

In [Divergent (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/), we learn what a divergent is and that they are rare. When Tris joins Dauntless, she meets Four who seems to be very careful, calculating and in control.

During the fear test, he figures out that Tris is a divergent because she can beat the test unlike any he has seen before. "Dauntless don't break the glass like that." But he doesn't do anything about it.

We see later on that his back tattoo consists of all of the faction symbols because, "he doesn't want to just be one thing".

Later when Dauntless is taken over and all of the members are under mind control, it's revealed that Four is pretending, he is very much immune to the mind control as Tris is (or maybe he didn't get injected?).

Based on these facts, I assume Four is also a divergent. But, his own fear test makes me think otherwise. Is he capable of escaping the test as Tris is, but chooses to endure it for the show or what?

Is Four a divergent and if so, is it revealed anywhere in the movie, subtle or otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, he is Divergent ... for all the reasons you've already given. You have answered your own question. I think the biggest clue was when Four was, just like Tris, not affected during the Dauntless takeover. He did get injected, but was not taken over (we know he was injected because he didn't accept the position of authority ... forgot what they called those slime buckets, lol). He and Tris knew how to control themselves, though others who did not realize they were Divergent, didn't know how to deal with not being controlled and therefor could not fool the controllers. Only Divergents would not be affected by the mind control ... Four was definitely one who was not.

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: @KushtrimP. ... Maybe in the book ... we are talking about the movie. Also, we are talking about *Divergent* and not *Allegiant*. We can only go on what has happened thus far. We don't know if something may or may not happen the same way as in the books. Who knows, Tris may not die in the final movie. Your answer would be correct in [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/), but not necessarily here.

Comment: In general I'm inclined to agree with @Paulster2, on the basis of this question asks about the character as portrayed in the movie, so unless the subsequent sequels state otherwise, we can only go on what we've seen in the first movie. Now, making a note of what's up with the character in the books? That's fine, but as this deals with the film portrayal, that's what needs to be addressed.

Comment: And everything we've been dealt thus far points towards him being Divergent. The OP points out everything which would make someone believe this *to this point in the storyline*.

Comment: Aha, ok then. I just meant that it's incorrect according to the books.

Comment: @KushtrimP. ... I have "toned down" my response somewhat.

Comment: You "toned down" by removing one word? It's still a blanket statement that may or may not be true. :p

Comment: @JohnP ... Yes. ;-)

Comment: @Paulster2 - Fair enough. :p

Answer (score 2):

Info from the "Allegiant" book. Spoilers ahead:

> No, he's not "totally" Divergent like Tris. He's still "genetically damaged", though he can withstand simulations like Divergents.

Quote from the book:

> He touches the screen again, and the screen changes, but it remains just as confusing, a web of lines, tangled threads of numbers.
> "This is the map of Tobias's genes," Matthew says. "As you can see, he has the right genetic components for simulation awareness, but he doesn't have the same 'healed' genes that Tris does."
> My throat is dry, and I feel like I've been given bad news, but I still haven't entirely grasped what that bad news is.
> "What does that mean?" I ask.
> "It means," Matthew says, "that you are not Divergent. Your genes are still damaged, but you have a genetic anomaly that allows you to be aware during simulations anyway. You have, in other words, the appearance of a Divergent without actually being one."
> I process the information slowly, piece by piece. I'm not Divergent. I'm not like Tris.
> I'm genetically damaged.

Comment: This is a good answer if the question was about the books. As it is, it is irrelevant to the movie. The question asks specifically about Divergent the movie and if it is revealed anywhere in the movie. -1.

Answer (score 1):

Just by going by the information of the movie it seems like four is divergent when the mind control syrum doesn't work on him but after he is captured he is all of a sudden not immune to the syrum at the end and it is up to tris when a gun is put to her head by four is that the only way four can shoot her is if he looks away, which ends up breaking his trance and allows them to break the trance of the syrum to the dauntless soldiers which saves many lives and brings the movie a happy ending ☺

Comment: Interesting point about the end when he was somehow affected. I don't recall how they did that though. Was it extra serum or something different and what does that mean for him as far as being a divergent?

Answer (score 0):

I think that he wants to protect her and does not want to kill her and tori wants to protect her from the fate her brother had which is death.  I think yes four is divergent because he doesn't have anyone close to him by blood that is divergent and he doesn't want to kill tris when she is divergent and they say divergents are dangorous

Answer (score -2):

No, he is genetically damaged. It's explained in Allegint.

Comment: What is allegent?

Comment: do you mean that the answer is in the book Allegiant?